# Bootstrap full width image header creating white space gap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I can't find solution for my problem. I am using part code from this template - http://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-full-width-pics/  where is image with full width in header.

Here is screenshot of my file - http://pasteboard.co/1E4k2zxf.png
You can see on right side there is white gap. And you can scroll down from left to right (it looks like more than 100% width)

In HTML i am using this class:

```
<body>
 <div class="image-bg"></div>
.............
```

It's in body, it's not inside any other tag. I am using clear bootstrap 3.3.6 and custom.css with these lines:

```
.image-bg {
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/g/1920/500') no-repeat center center scroll;
  height: 384px;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

And still it's not working. It creates margin or padding on right side of image, but it shouldn't. There isn't any other CSS file except bootstrap and custom.css.

Thanks for you ideas :)

Comment: post a fiddle.. it will be easier to understand with a live example..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a problem with the image container, it's the navbar at the top causing the extra margin. See screenshot:

[image: problem]

A quick fix is to add

```
body {
   overflow-x: hidden 
}
```

Or work out what is causing the extra width on the navbar

Comment: Well but it's default CDN bootstrap from official, there shouldn't be extra margin for navbar in default.

Comment: Well the problem lies in there not your image banner, you're welcome by the way

Comment: Thank you very much. overflow-x works, but i am still trying to find why navbar more than 100% width.

Answer (score 0):

just you need to give body margin use below css to fix issue

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: In https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css  is margin: 0 for body.

Comment: yes but it didnt link properly to your html add below link in your html page it will be solved  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the negative margin from `.image-bg-fluid-height` and add `background-size: cover`.

Hope it helps.